# How to make LDAP authentication work over EAP

Tags: freeradius

i'm working on setting up an 802.1x authentication though a 6224 Switch Dell To a FreeRADIUS who will check in an LDAP server for the user and retreive the TunnelPrivateGroupId and the others informations for the switch.

I already set up custom attributes and the attribute map on the FreeRADIUS to retreive my custom attributes from the LDAP.

In localhost, the authentication works fine and i can retreive my custom attributes.
But though my computer (who speak with EAP-PEAP), my FreeRadius validate the module ldap but never set the Auth-Type to LDAP.

My Computer --> Switch --> FreeRADIUS --> LDAP

[screenshoot of an authentication attempt with my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAN8I.png)

Where the red arrow is where the Auth-Type is writen by the module when the authentication is ok, but it never happened.
As i say again, in localhost, the authentication works fine and the Auth-Type is writen by the module because it's not going though the EAP PEAP method.

I made every modifications on the default and inner-tunnel sites to get it worked in localhost and from my switch.

If you have any idea, i take it ^^
(i try to explain my problem as mush as i can. Sorry for any english errors, it's not my main language)

Answer (score 0):

See that line `WARNING: No "known good" password found in LDAP...`.  It's not just there for decoration :)

The problem is you haven't correctly mapped an LDAP attribute to the `Password-With-Header` attribute in FreeRADIUS.

Verify that there are mappings in your [LDAP attrmap](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/ldap.attrmap) file for `Password-With-Header` and `NT-Password` and that the LDAP attributes (on the right side of the mapping) actually exist in the User object in LDAP.

Which EAP methods you can perform are determined by what password attributes you have.  If you have a hashed version of the password in LDAP and no `NT-Password` attribute, you are limited to `EAP-TTLS-PAP`, and you should comment out any references to PEAP in your `eap.conf` file to prevent the server from negotiating it.